# Why use double exclamation marks (!!) when parsing options map input?

Tags: elixir

For example, in [`ExUnit.Case.__using__/1`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.7.4/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/case.ex#L211) macro:

```
defmacro __using__(opts) do
  # ...
  quote do
    async = !!unquote(opts)[:async]
    # ...
  end
  # ...
end
```

where `:async` is a boolean option when `use`ing `ExUnit.Case`.

```
defmodule AssertionTest do
  use ExUnit.Case, async: true

  test "always pass" do
    assert true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means negating the statement twice ([`Kernel.!/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#!/1)). Found the best description on why doing this in [`Credo`'s documentation](https://github.com/rrrene/credo/blob/v1.0.0/lib/credo/check/refactor/double_boolean_negation.ex):

> Having double negations in your code obscures a parameters original
>   value.
>
> ```
>   # NOT preferred
>   !!var
> ```
>
> This will return `false` for `false` and `nil`, and `true` for
>   anything else.   At first this seems like an extra clever shorthand to
>   cast anything truthy to   `true` and anything non-truthy to `false`.
>   But in most scenarios you want to   be explicit about your input
>   parameters (because it is easier to reason about   edge-cases,
>   code-paths and tests).
>
> Also: `nil` and `false` do mean two different things.
>
> A scenario where you want this kind of flexibility, however, is
>   parsing   external data, e.g. a third party JSON-API where a value is
>   sometimes `null`   and sometimes `false` and you want to normalize
>   that before handing it down   in your program.   In these case, you
>   would be better off making the cast explicit by introducing   a helper
>   function:
>
> ```
>   # preferred
>   defp present?(nil), do: false
>   defp present?(false), do: false
>   defp present?(_), do: true
> ```
>
> This makes your code more explicit than relying on the implications
>   of `!!`.

In the question's example it was necessery because if the `:async` option is not present, then getting that key will result in `nil`, but that needs to be converted to `false` for later checks that only look for boolean values.

Comment: It worth noting that credo itself [tags this rule as `:controversial`](https://github.com/rrrene/credo/blob/3ef7c5a1dd5098e74955e2ac91edbef43457a5f4/lib/credo/check/refactor/double_boolean_negation.ex#L5) meaning it is a non-default opt-in check. There certainly are valid use cases for double negation.